# Sync data including createdby field with Salesforce using Heroku connect

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

We've a **customer portal** which is accessible to customers. They can create lead an cases from the portal.

Customer has existing native mobile app they wants to replicate lead creation functionality for `customer portal` users using the mobile app.

Partner wsdl is being used to authenticate and maintain session of the users.

Heroku connect is being used to sync Lead object with Salesforce. A Salesforce admin user is being used for syncing purpose. When a lead is created in mobile app it is sent to Heroku and from **Heroku** it is being synced in real time with Salesforce.

The created by for the Lead is appearing to be Admin user which seems logically  correct.

> My questions are:
>
> 1. Is there any way the created by User can be set to Customer Portal User?
> 2. The assignment rules are running while Lead is being created from Portal but its not the same when created from Heroku. As per
>      Salesforce documents, default behavior is it should run assignment
>      rules, when no header value is passed.
>       Any pointer on how it can be resolved, I know using trigger but wanted to seek opinion on any other approach community may have.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Heroku Connect doesn't have a way to specify a different "created by" user. It's always the user that you've authorized Heroku Connect to use.
2. As you saw, the default in Heroku Connect is not to run assignment rules, but it's possible to request that assignment rules be run. Currently, only Heroku can change this setting for you. Please submit a Heroku support ticket if you still need this to be enabled.

Comment: Submitted ticket with Heroku and Salesforce already but none of them is supporting this. So had to do it custom way.

Comment: For #2 about assignment rules, Heroku Connect does support it. It sounds like you don't need it any more, but if you need it in the future, please send me the link to your support ticket and I can enable it for you (I work on Heroku at Salesforce).